# Working with full height content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have made this code:

http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/xHpqJ

I made a code that does the content have the same height of the window. But I wish he'd stop doing that when the window width is less than 768px. Could help me do this? Thank you in advance

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        $('.featuredContent').height($(window).height() - $(".header").height());
     }).resize()
  });
```

Comment: use if($(window).height()>768){$('.featuredContent').height($(window).height() - $(".header").height());}

Answer (score 2):

You could add `if ($(window).width() > 768)` before setting the height:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
  $(window).on("resize", function () {
     if ($(window).width() > 768)
       $('.featuredContent').height($(window).height() - $(".header").height());
  }).resize();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).on("resize", function () {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {return;}
  $('.featuredContent').height($(window).height() - $(".header").height());
  }).resize();
});
```